# Reference mocked class

Tags: c++, reference, c++14, googletest

my code is structured like this

```
class B
{
   virtual void bar() { //something};
}

class A {

void foo(B& b) { b.bar();}

}
```

I wanted to create a gtest mock for this but I'm running into an issue...

```
class Btest : public B
{
  public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, bar, (), (override));
};

TEST()
{
   A a;
   Btest b;
   a.foo(b); <--- no instance matches argument list
}
```

How do I implement a mock like this? If I upcast wouldn't it just call the non mocked version of that method?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. The shown code snippets have a lot of syntax and access errors. Except the syntax errors, the complained error `no instance matches` can't be reproduced by the shown code. https://godbolt.org/z/a6zd7q75K

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code. One way to fix it is to make the `bar` and `foo` methods public:

```
class B {
 public:
  virtual void bar() {
    // something
  }
};

class A {
 public:
  void foo(B& b) { b.bar(); }
};

class Btest : public B {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(void, bar, (), (override));
};

TEST(a, b) {
  A a;
  Btest b;
  a.foo(b);
}
```